# Fetch don't work in developer console in react, but work inside other website

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this snippet that i put in firefox dev tools:

```
        fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/u7cyd")
            .then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
            .then(function(json) {
            console.log(json);
            return json;
            });
```

It didn't work when i try to put this on devloper tools on react page, but it work on any other page and returns correct value. 
I try to keep my self sane, but this is above me i tried on 2 react dev examples.When i try it on react page a recive:

TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

It work in Chromium, i think it is just Firefox error. Exactly the same code on exactly the same app. I am sorry.

Comment: Any more details about the error? Does it work in the Chrome console?

Comment: sounds CORS related

Comment: I tried this on a CRA app, it works just fine.

Comment: @JaromandaX This website allow CORS request

Comment: you're right, sorry, didn't even think to check if the URL in the question was real :p

Comment: it's almost like fetch isn't the native fetch ... if you `console.log(fetch+'')` is the output `function fetch() {
    [native code]
}`

Comment: @HoriaComan  It works in Chromium, i think it is just Firefox error. Exactly the same code on exactly the same app. I am sorry.

Comment: Did you bother to check the network tab to see what Firefox is reporting about the request? Is there even a request being made?

Comment: @poke It only displays TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. And there is no request in network tab using (55.0.3 (32 bit))

Answer (score 0):

It works in Chromium, i think it is just Firefox (55.0.3 (32 bit) error. I don't still know why. Exactly the same code on exactly the same app.

Comment: Does your Firefox supports fetch() ?

I suggest you to check version of Firefox you're using and check if that version has fetch support built-in.

Comment: Yes it does, but i don't know why on react with babel page it doesn't work.